# What does (function() mean in this particular code segment?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mozilla

I'm (re)learning Ajax from the Mozilla site on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started, and I'm faced with this segment of code:

```
(function () {
    var httpRequest;
    document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function () {
        makeRequest('test.html');
    };

    function makeRequest(url) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        if (!httpRequest) {
            alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
        httpRequest.open('GET', url);
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    function alertContents() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                alert(httpRequest.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }
} //missing closing bracket added by bwalton 5/11/11.   )();
```

While I managed to understand the code and get it working, it's not until I stripped off the "(function() {" part at the top and all the end braces at the end of this code segment. The thing is I don't understand the purpose of" (function{", and it seems neither does FF. (It doesn't recognize this segment as Javascript until I stripped off the "(function{" portions. Does anyone know the purpose of this segment of code? I knew I've seen it somewhere as well, and this time I want to know exactly what it means.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(function() { /* code here */ })();` creates an anonymous function and executes it in place. One of the purposes is to create a local scope.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
(function() {
    ...
})();
```

creates a function and calls it immediately, with its own scope.  A common term for this is an IIFE - "immediately invoked function expression".

In this case, you've inadvertently combined the last two lines, so the single line comment mentioning `bwalton` has broken the code by removing the trailing `) ();`.

Without the trailing `()`  you have a function reference, but it's not invoked.

All you need to do to fix your copy of the code is add a carriage return after `bwalton 5/11/11.`.

Comment: You're one parenthesis short, aren't you? It's worth noting that the initial opening parenthesis and it's closing pair can be left out, but serve as a convention (as a visual indicator) that this function will be immediately invoked. They are not required. However, the `();` at the end is definitely required for invocation.

Comment: @JordanArsenault yes - I missed one out - thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Your combined comments helped me understand it completely. Cheers.:)

Comment: To clarify my last comment -- in the context of the above answer, the external parens are actually **required**, or the javascript parser will throw an error. The parser makes distinctions between function declarations and function expressions. The external parens are not required for expressions, for instance `var i = function(){ return 10; }();` but **are** required for declarations, as above. See [Ben Alman's article on IIFE's](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#highlighter_210366) (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions)

Comment: @JordanArsenault FWIW, there's other ways of fooling the parser into recognising a function expression without enclosing it in parens.

Answer (score 0):

Do u see that 
    ()();

that is a call parenthesis attached to some value. Now.

```
(function(){});
```

is a function, an anonymous function closed under the parenthesis.
 Adding it all up.

```
(function(){}) ();
```

a call to a function enclosed in parenthesis.
Amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

As explained above this is a closure, see the links for more information about closures http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/